# Is there a way to display HTML code in an IPython notebook before widgets in the same output cell?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a IPython notebook using widgets. For this I want some HTML headers followed by the input widgets. This I am achieving like this:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.display import HTML

class buttons(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.buttons = []
        for i in xrange(6):

            self.buttons.append( widgets.Button(description = str(i)))
            self.buttons[-1].on_click(self.handle_submit)
            self.buttons[-1].margin=20

        display(HTML("<h1> Heading </h1>"))

        display( widgets.HBox((self.buttons)) )

        self.text = widgets.Text(value="21")
        display(self.text)

    def handle_submit(self, sender):
        self.show(int(self.text.value))

    def show(self, x=None):
        print(1+1)

b = buttons()
```

However, even though I call the `display(HTML("...."))` function BEFORE the `display(widgets(...))` function I get the following output (where the order is opposite):
[image]

Is there a way to make it look like this:

[image]

I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build everything together using VBox:

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.display import HTML

class buttons(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.buttons = []
        for i in xrange(6):

            self.buttons.append( widgets.Button(description = str(i)))
            self.buttons[-1].on_click(self.handle_submit)
            self.buttons[-1].margin=20

        self.text = widgets.Text(value="21")

        self.header = widgets.HTML(description='',value='<h1> Heading </h1>')
        self.everything = widgets.VBox([self.header,widgets.HBox((self.buttons)),self.text])
        display(self.everything)

        #display(HTML("<h1> Heading </h1>"))

        #display( widgets.HBox((self.buttons)) )


        #display(self.text)

    def handle_submit(self, sender):
        self.show(int(self.text.value))

    def show(self, x=None):
        print(1+1)

b = buttons()
```